# How to call class as an Activity when class has extends LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity, crash

as my title says I'm here with a problem in Android studio (JAVA) with my app, how to call class as an Activity when class has extends LinearLayout?

My class is:
 `public class CustomCalendar extends LinearLayout {`

My code where I try to call it:

```
 Intent customCalendar = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CustomCalendarActivity.class);
 startActivity(customCalendar);
```

I tried to make this:

```
 public class CustomCalendarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    CustomCalendar customCalendar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        customCalendar = (CustomCalendar) findViewById(R.id.kalendoriaus_virsus);
        customCalendar.SetUpCalendar();
    }
}
```

My crash is this:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.kalendorius.CustomCalendar.SetUpCalendar()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.kalendorius.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:75)
```

75 Line is:

```
 startActivity(customCalendar);
```

How I setup my calendar:

My kalendorius.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/kalendoriaus_virsus"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/soft_blue_green"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/atgalBtn"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/back" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dabartineData"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Data"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

That's just a bit code where I use that kalendorius_virsus.

DONE. I figure out what was the problem. I just forgot to generate for database constructor:D Thank you for everyone who tried to help.

Comment: check that kalendoriaus_virsus is the id in the XML.You may want to add the XML and more code..Error may be due to customCalendar  being null then calling setupcalendar();

Comment: Did you call `setContentView()` in `onCreate()` of your `Activity`? You need to do this to tell the `Activity` which layout XML file to use.

Comment: Which one activity ? In MainActivity where I call CustomCalendar?

Comment: No, in `CustomCalendarActivity`

Comment: But it looks like the crash occurs in `MainActivity` in an `onClick()` method. Add the code for that method (includes line 75) to your question please (just edit the question)

Comment: The problem isn't in the `SetupCalendar()` method. The problem is that you are trying to call `SetupCalendar()` on a `null` reference. That's the problem. It never actually gets to execute the code in `SetupCalendar()`.

Comment: I tried that way, but still no use :D.

Comment: So what shall I do ? David Wasser cause I did not really understood what you mean by that ?

Comment: The crash occurs in `MainActivity` in an `onClick()` method. Add the code for that method (includes line 75) to your question please (just edit the question)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is 
customCalendar = (CustomCalendar) findViewById(R.id.kalendoriaus_virsus);

The groupView LinearLayout with id kalendorias_virsus in the kalendorias.xml is not a CustomCalendar so always return null.

You need to understand how to properly user a costum view

basic example CustomView ->

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {

    public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        View view =  LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.costum, null);

        this.addView(view);
    }

    public void setCustomText(String text){
        TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
        textview.setText(text);
    }
}
```

layout custom.xml ->

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:gravity="center">

    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

activity.xml->

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.example.myapplication.CustomView
        android:id="@+id/customViewId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity class->

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        CustomView customView = findViewById(R.id.customViewId);
        customView.setCustomText("Welcome ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean like that ? *Check my answer*

Comment: And I tried this before but it's still as a null.. CustomCalendar customCalendar = findViewById(R.id.kalendoriaus_virsus);
                    customCalendar.SetUpCalendar();

Comment: you need put in layout "kalendorius".xml file something like this 
   <com.example.myapplication.CustomCalendar
        android:id="@+id/kalendoriaus_virsus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

and you need to make sure that you override the method  
public CustomCalendar(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs)
on CustomCalendar.class for work. See the example above

Comment: I had that. I just added my a bit of code of kalendorius xml

Answer (score 0):

You have many errors in your code. We still need more information to determine why you are getting a `NullPointerException` (NPE) in the `MainActivity.onClick()` method. However, this will for sure crash:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    customCalendar = (CustomCalendar) findViewById(R.id.kalendoriaus_virsus);
    customCalendar.SetUpCalendar();
}
```

because `customCalendar` will be `null` because you have not called `setContentView()` before calling `findBiewById()`.

You need to add

```
    setContentView(R.layout.XXXXXX);
```

before you call `findViewById()`. The `XXXXXX` above must be the name of your layout XML file (without the `.xml` file extension).

Comment: After I added this I got this error:  java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to com.example.kalendorius.CustomCalendar
        at com.example.kalendorius.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:73)

Comment: Yes, because in the layout XML file you have a `LinearLayout` declared with `id=kalendoriaus_virsus`, not a `CustomCalender`. If you want to use a `CustomCalendar` instead of `LinearLayout` then you need to declare that in the XML file. Instead of using `<LinearLayout>` you should use `<com.example.kalendorius.CustomCalendar>` in your layout file.